# Loaded ubuntu + ROS kinetic (on dual booted W8.1 box)

Tags: ubuntu, ros, catkin

Following YouTube ROS Course #1. All apps work,etc. Almost half way through ROS #1 tutorial, while in my catkin_ws$ directory (Per ROS Tutorial) I typed "catkin build [whatever]. Reply from ROS: "catkin: command not found" Any help appreciated. John.

Answer (score 0):

The command you want to write is `catkin_build`.